# Rewrite ^(.*)$ (everything) to a specific directory doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The following rewrite rule throws an error 500 for some weird reason:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

If I modify the rule by adding just one character (like `x`) after `^`, it works; every file starting with `x` gets read from the desired folder:

```
RewriteRule ^x(.*)$ folder/x$1 [L]
```

This doesn't work either:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ folder/$1 [L]
```

Also, the first and the last example does work on localhost, but not on the remote server.

The remote server uses LiteSpeed server if that's relevant.

Comment: I changed it to `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\/?&=]*)$ folder/$1 [L]`, which also doesn't work, but **if remove the `\/` part**, it works. But that is still not an adequate solution.

Comment: Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/folder` subdirectory? If so, what does this contain?

Comment: ... do you have any other directives in this (root?) `.htaccess` file?

Comment: _Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/folder` subdirectory?_
— No, I don't.

Comment: _... do you have any other directives in this (root?)_
— The time I asked this question, the only directives were the ones I copied into the question.

Comment: _"The following rewrite rule throws an error 500 for some weird reason"_ - unfortunately, often times people say stuff like this _for some weird reason_, instead of going and checking what the error log has to say about the cause.

Comment: *"instead of going and checking what the error log has to say"* - You're right, sorry. However, I couldn't get my hands on the log, and customer service didn't help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

The joke's on me. I tried the same thing on localhost, and the log made it clear:

**The rule produced a loop. I replaced the `[L]` flag with `[END]`, and the problem was solved.**

###### Reason:

The `[L]` flag only stops the processing of further rules for the current iteration, `[END]` fully terminates the whole process, preventing loops from happening.